# cannot update during an existing state transition react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

in my app, I am able to get the values, distance and names of location from an array by using the fuctions below. However, I am unable to dispatch the values obtained from them in my redux store using the mapDispatchToProps, 
which is for example

```
      handleNavigation() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LocationLists');
        this.props.totalDistanceChange(this.totalDistance()).
      }


      <Button
        onPress={this.handleNavigation.bind(this)}
      />





    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
     totalDistanceChange: totalDistance=> {
       dispatch(totalDistanceChange(totalDistance));
     }
    });
```

I keep getting cannot update during an existing state transition.
below are just my functions as I wanted to keep it as simple as possible, kindly correct where appropriate.

```
      totalDistance = () => {
        const { selectedItemObjects } = this.state;
        const total = selectedItemObjects.reduce((result, { Distance }) => result += Distance, 0);
        return total.toFixed(1);
      }

      totalValue = () => {
        const { selectedItemObjects } = this.state;
        const total = selectedItemObjects.reduce((result, { Value }) => result += Value, 0);
        return total;
      }

      renderLocationText = () => {
        const { selectedItemObjects } = this.state;
        return selectedItemObjects.length ?
        `${selectedItemObjects.map((item, i) => {
          let label = `${item.name}, `;
          if (i === selectedItemObjects.length - 2) label = `${item.name} and `;
          if (i === selectedItemObjects.length - 1) label = `${item.name}.`;
          return label;
        }).join('')}`
        :
        null;
      }
```

my question is how can i pass the values obtained to my redux store

Comment: Please insert the context in which you are calling `this.props.totalDistanceChange(this.totalDistance())`. Usually the error you are mentioning is related to some infinity loop over `this.setState()`

Comment: made the necessary changes to the code above

Answer (score -1):

fixed it by converting it to a string

```
  handleNavigation() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('LocationLists');
    this.props.totalDistanceChange(this.totalDistance().toString()).
  }
```